# Cannot get page breaks to work using css and prince

Tags: html, css, page-break, princexml

I cannot get page breaks into my pdf using css and prince. The second table touches the first one. What am I doing wrong? I think I may have misunderstood how to use instructions for print in css, from my perspective it looks like I'm doing exactly what the user guide is telling me ([link](http://www.princexml.com/doc/9.0/page-breaks/))

My code is as follows:

```css
@page { size: 210mm  297mm;   
}

chapter {page-break-before: always;} 

table.page{
  width:14cm;
  font-family:"Times New Roman";
  font-size: 12pt;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align:justify;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

td.number{
  width:1.8cm;
  font-family:"Times New Roman" ;
  font-size: 12pt;
  text-align:justify;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

td.content{
  width:12cm;
  font-family:"Times New Roman";
  font-size: 12pt;
  text-align:justify;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <chapter>
        <table class="page">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                     <h1>Title </h1>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="number">
                    <div>1</div>
                </td>
                <td class="content">
                    <div>this is some text</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </chapter>
    <chapter>
        <table class="page">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                     <h1>Title 2</h1>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="number">
                    <div>2</div>
                </td>
                <td class="content">
                    <div>this is some more text</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </chapter>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer myself: chapter is considered empty. Works if I use the table class="page" element to specify the page break.

Answer (score 0):

## Applies to block elements only

> **Applies to:** *block*-level elements in the normal flow of the root element. User agents may also apply it to other elements like
>   table-row elements.

It won't apply on an empty `<div>` that won't generate a box.

> **Note:** this property is in progress of being replaced by the more generic [`break-before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-before). This new property also handles column and
>   region breaks and is syntactically compatible with
>   `page-break-before`.
>
> Before using `page-break-before`, check if you can use break-before
>   instead. In the future `page-break-before` will be a mere alias for
>   some values of it.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-before)

## Solution

One can get around this limitation, simply by converting the `inline` element into a `block` element (assuming you can afford to do so).

```
.pagebreak {
    display: block;
    page-break-before: always;
}
```

Comment: Prince XML has no `break-before` CSS property yet.